# How to start deb package after install automatically

Tags: debian, packaging

I can install deb package via my repository as follow

```
$ sudo apt install my_app
```

then the package manager will fetch `my_app` and installed. But I have to start it manually. 
 My aim is when I installed an app that should run without any further action like any native deb packages
 i.e

```
$sudo apt install syslog-ng
```

installed.

```
$ sudo service --status-all 
[+] syslog-ng
```

PS: Sure I can manually create service, but this is what I try to automate.

Comment: That's the job of the package - it should come with a service file, and a postinstall maintainer script that will start, enable or restart the service as needed.

Comment: Do you mean .service file should be in deb package?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/syslog-ng-core/filelist for example: both `/etc/init.d/syslog-ng` and `/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service` are present. You can see [the use of dh-systemd in `debian/rules`](https://github.com/gcsideal/syslog-ng-debian/blob/debian/unstable/debian/rules#L207).

Comment: See also [Debian package containing combined systemd service and associated executed binary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/551927/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt this exactly what I looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your post/title as there is no mention about a reboot in post

To start app immediately after install You can try using

```
$ sudo apt install my_app ; my_app
```

That will first install that app, and after that execute it.

Comment: I guess you missed the point, what you wrote is completely manual what I try to avoid it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess your question wasn't clear enough on that